# How to transform world position to local position in unity 3d for itween

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, transform, itween

I am struggling in problem that convert world position in local position. i am using iTween plugin in unity. And there is an argument of `position` in iTween which is take world position and but i want to use local position in pixel to move the object in iTween.
I tried with `transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(0,0,0)` i don't thing it is working according to pixel position.

like this example:

`iTween.MoveTo(gameObject,iTween.Hash("position",new Vector(0,0,0) ,  "time" ,.6, "easetype" ,"easeincubic"));`

the argument of position iTween take in World position but i want to convert in pixel position. 
Like i pass `new Vector(450,50,0);`

your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `Camera.current.WorldToScreenPoint(Vector3 vector)` which returns a Vector3 with x and y in camera space, meaning between values between 0 and 1.

By multipling those values with `Screen.width` or `Screen.height` would give you the position in pixel.

Answer (score 4):

remember to add: `"islocal", true` parameter in `iTween.Hash`

Answer (score 1):

`"islocal' = true` is not working properly in moveto function. There is another solution.

Here is my code :

```
iTween.MoveTo(gameObject,iTween.Hash("position",Target,"time",_Duration,"delay",_Delay,"easetype",_eEaseType,"islocal",true,"looptype",_eLoop));
```

Comment: iTween.MoveTo(gameObject, iTween.Hash("position", Target , "time", _Duration, "islocal", true, "easetype", iTween.EaseType.linear));